# jQuery function is not calling onchange event in Spring MVC

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, onchange

I am working on spring mvc and with that I am using ajax jQuery and but I am able to add element in it. But I am not able to call jQuery when I am making change event into the Dropdownbox. Can I have any suggestion here what I have tried?

JSP CODE:-

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Model Registration</h1>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="employee">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">
                            <spring:message code="label.firstname" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="surname">
                            <spring:message code="label.lastname" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="surname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="email">
                            <spring:message code="label.email" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="company">
                            <spring:message code="label.telephone" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="company" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="salary">
                            <spring:message code="label.salary" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="salary" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="country">
                            <spring:message code="label.country" />
                        </form:label></td>
                    <td><form:select id="cbox" path="country"
                            items="${countrylist}" /></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                        value="<spring:message code="label.add"/>" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#cbox').on('change',function() {
        alert("change done!!!");
    });

    $('#cbox').trigger('change');
});
```

html source page:-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
        <script src="/SpringEmployeeSpringHibernateJquery/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/SpringEmployeeSpringHibernateJquery/resources/js/jquerycall.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <h1 align="center">Employee Edit list</h1>
    <button id="clickchech" value="Clicked" onclick="first()">Click Here</button><br><br>

    <!-- <button id="clickstate" value="Clicked">Click Here</button><br><br> -->

    <div id="result">Main From Data</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the pure html pendant of `<form:select id="cbox" path="country" items="${countrylist}" />`? Please replace this line with the html pendant in your post.

Comment: i did not got u what u trying to say? okey i am replacing with whole document.

Comment: Look i have changed that.

Comment: We need just the HTML source code that your/our browser has received, because the Jquery code will be executed into the browser, not somewhere else. That way is helpful to determine is it an issue with Javascript or the "configuration" of you select box.

Comment: i have posted whole page of that including html code. its only html code that i have posted and ya one thing is that other event like click is working fine in same file. so its issue about something else not in the inclusion.

Comment: Please don't make it to complecated, keep it simple. Call the website into the browser, then press the right mouse button and select from the occured menu the option "Show source code". After that, press the keys CTRL + a and then ctrl + c und paste here the source code into your post.

Comment: okey just min let me do that.

Comment: Ok, I can see the pure html code. So where is the html element with the id 'cbox'?

Comment: one call is replacing the div and then that register page is replacing  there then it appears.

Comment: so then post also all nessacary javascript code, that allows other users to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is one thing you can just check it out once that are u including that all the java script libraries into the all the page where u using that all libraries. ??

it means that if i am including other page then u still need to include that libraries into the other pages as well.